# TypeVar and assignment expresion

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I used assignment expression (aka walrus operator, defined in [PEP 572](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/)) to define a type `T`. It seemed an elegant solution, but apparently mypy does not agree.

For the following code:

```py
# Python 3.10.4

from collections.abc import Sequence
from typing import TypeVar

def foo(seq: Sequence[T := TypeVar('T')]) -> T:
    return seq[0]
```

mypy reports:

```bash
error: Invalid type comment or annotation
error: Name "T" is not defined
```

Is walrus somehow forbidden with `TypeVar`?

Comment: That's not what walrus is for - readability went down the drain. Maybe mypy didn't implement walrus because it normally doesn't change anything in a readable code...?

Comment: mypy is static analysis, it doesn't actually execute your code. Obviously in case of TypeVar there must be some support for recognising the basic assignment pattern but more complex forms are unlikely to work. Also there is a note here https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#generics _"A `TypeVar()` expression must always directly be assigned to a variable (it should not be used as part of a larger expression)."_

Comment: @Anentropic I think that is the answer. Thanks for the reference. Someone could argue that the assignment expression is actually direct assignment to a variable ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is **really** bad idea.

Suppose you have annotations future imported - then this is just a long string, no assignment happens. Suppose you want then to `cast(T, something)` in function body. If `mypy` accepts this, it misses runtime error:

> NameError: name "T" is not defined

So in this case [PEP563](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/) changes behavior of your code.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from collections.abc import Sequence
from typing import TypeVar


def foo(seq: Sequence[T := TypeVar('T')]) -> T:
    return cast(T, seq[0])
```

You could `cast('T', ...)` instead, but this is not-really-annotations-only case.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with python 3.12 (assuming that [PEP695](https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/) is accepted) it will be possible to use even more elegant and powerful syntax with square brackets that will replace `TypeVar`:

```py
from typing import Callable

def func[**P, R](cb: Callable[P, R], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
    ...
```